# Add stack protection removal flags to apache compilation script

Tags: security, compilation, makefile

For study purposes I'd like to test some buffer overflow exploits on an old 1.3.x version of apache webserver.
Anyway I have the stack protection on, so it doesn't work or at least I think it doesn't for this reason.
In order to disable protections I have to compile with these flags:

```
-fno-stack-protector -z execstack
```

but I don't know how to add them to apache compilation process..I never did something like this!
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
CFLAGS="-fno-stack-protector" LDFLAGS="-z execstack" ./configure [...]
```

`CFLAGS` is for the compiler, `execstack` is a linker option, so it should go in `LDFLAGS`. Or, if supported you can get the compiler to pass the linker options -with `-Wl`, so:

```
CFLAGS="-fno-stack-protector -Wl,-z,execstack" ./configure [...]
```

See the `INSTALL` file in the Apache source archive for more details.

It's useful to inspect or compare the generated top-level `Makefile`, you should see your parameters in either or both of `EXTRA_CFLAGS` and `EXTRA_LDFLAGS`.

Given the task you have, if you're running a Linux distribution which has a periodic [pre-linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelinking) and [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) task, you should check that you install Apache to a path that does *not* get processed, otherwise your testing might be complicated when your Apache binary is "fixed" one night...

Check if `prelink` is installed with

```
 dpkg -l prelink      # Ubuntu/Debian derived
 rpm -qv prelink      # CentOS/Red Hat derived
```

and check the configuration (usually) in `/etc/prelink.conf` and one of: `/etc/defaults/prelink` or `/etc/sysconfig/prelink` .

On Ubuntu (but *not* on CentOS/RH) directories under `/usr/local/` (`bin`, `sbin`, `lib`) *are* included for processing.  If you install Apache to the default `/usr/local/apache` then it should be untouched, or if you want to be thorough you can add a directory blacklist (`-b`) line to `/etc/prelink.conf`

Comment: Can you be clearer about the last part please? I have ubuntu 12.04 so I guess it's my case...apache is currently installed in /usr/local path is that processed?

Comment: Updated answer. On Ubuntu it shouldn't be a problem if you install to `/usr/local/apache`.